# Why is only the first cookie being set in Windows Server 2019 IIS 10, same code sets all cookies on other servers?

Tags: php, iis, cookies

I'm rather new to IIS, so please forgive my inexperience. I have a very unusual problem. Several PHP software packages seem to have trouble, especially when logging in a user, when multiple cookies are being written within the same script. I've simplified the code down to the following example.

When I run the below script, on our production server running Windows Server 2019 with IIS 10.0.17763.1, only the first cookie is seen as being set.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

setcookie('CookieONE', 'one cookie AH HA HA!', time()+3600, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], TRUE, TRUE);

setcookie('Cookie_too', 'two', time()+3600, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], TRUE, TRUE);

setcookie('Cookie_tree', '3tree', time()+3600, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], TRUE, TRUE);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_COOKIE);
echo '</pre>';
```

When I run this exact same script on our other servers, one running Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.0.14393.0, and another running Windows 2012 with IIS 8.0.9200.16384, all three cookies are seen as being set on these two servers.

All information rendered from a phpinfo() on the servers matches. Leading me to believe I may have a misconfiguration or a bug somewhere in this Windows Server 2019 instance.

Greatly appreciate any help you could provide. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but cookies set with `setcookie` will NOT populated in `$_COOKIE` until the NEXT page load.

Comment: Thanks, @MER. Unfortunately, after several refreshes, still only the first cookie is showing in the output on the troubled server, but all cookies show on the other 2 servers.

Comment: do u see the cookies in the browser's dev tools?

Comment: Also, what happens if you comment out the first `setcookie` line? Do you then just see `Cookie_too`?

Comment: Negative. The Cookie Manager extension gives me the same results as dumpint $_COOKIE.

Comment: Yes, commenting out the first set cookie, will set the second, but still not the third. On both of the other servers, all three cookies are set at the same time. This chokes things like WordPress that wants to set a cookie to test the browser's cookie compatibility before writing the user's login cookie.

Comment: You said the above code was condensed from the actual code. Be sure you are setting the cookies before you output anything else to the page.

Comment: The condensed code is producing the same results, as the major products, nothing being output before setting all the cookies!

Comment: That's all the ideas I got. :(

Comment: which php version you are using on both the iis server?

Comment: All three servers are running PHP v7.3.7.